# How to find gain g from z,p,k in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

Matlab `zp2sos` returns `[sos, g]` but in python equivalent library `zpk2sos` returns only `sos`. How to calculate gain g in python.

```
ts=(length(data1)/128);
Wp = [1 4]/(fs/2); Ws = [0.5 4.5]/(fs/2);
Rp = 3; Rs = 40;
[n,Wn] = buttord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs);
[z, p, k] = butter(n,Wn,'bandpass');
[sos,g] = zp2sos(z,p,k);
filt = dfilt.df2sos(sos,g);
```

I'm converting this Matlab code to Python but can't find the library required to calculate gain g returned by Matlab `zp2sos` function.

Comment: The title and most of the question are about `g`, but in the last sentence you ask a separate question about `dfilt.df2sos`.  I think you should create a new stackoverflow question for that.   One question per topic keeps the issue focused and easier to answer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the form

```
[sos,g] = zp2sos(z,p,k);
```

`g` is the same as `k`.

For example,

```
> [sos, g] = zp2sos([-1 0.5 0.6], [-0.5 0.1+0.25j 0.1-0.25j 0.9], 3);
> g
g = 3
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. But can you please tell me if there's any library in python equivalent to matlab `dfilt.df2sos` ??

Comment: Isn't `g` supposed to be a vector ??

Comment: No, `g` is a scalar; it is the "overall gain".   Note that if you use `sos = zp2sos(z, p, k)`, the gain is embedded in the first of the second order sections.  See the [zp2sos documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/zp2sos.html) for more details.

Comment: Ok. I thought it's a vector because in [`df2sos()`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dfilt.df2sos.html) doc its stated that `g` is a gain vector.